Unable to install miniconda on Ubuntu(WSL)
I am trying to install miniconda on Ubuntu(WSL) using the instructions on the official installation page: https://docs.anaconda.com/free/miniconda/miniconda-install/
I am able to download the package but while installing it, I receive an error message shown below-
Miniconda3 will now be installed into this location:
/home/suma/miniconda3

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/home/suma/miniconda3] >>>
PREFIX=/home/suma/miniconda3
Unpacking payload ...

Installing base environment...


# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "conda/exception_handler.py", line 17, in __call__
      File "conda/cli/main.py", line 66, in main_subshell
      File "conda/base/context.py", line 472, in __init__
      File "conda/common/configuration.py", line 1416, in _set_search_path
      File "boltons/setutils.py", line 125, in __init__
      File "boltons/setutils.py", line 355, in update
      File "conda/common/configuration.py", line 1389, in _expand_search_path
      File "pathlib.py", line 1322, in is_file
      File "pathlib.py", line 1097, in stat
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/chandsum/miniconda3/.condarc'

`$ /home/suma/miniconda3/_conda install --offline --file /home/suma/miniconda3/pkgs/env.txt -yp /home/suma/miniconda3`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
           CONDA_CHANNELS=https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main,https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=/home/chandsum/miniconda3/bin/conda
CONDA_EXTRA_SAFETY_CHECKS=no
          CONDA_PKGS_DIRS=/home/suma/miniconda3/pkgs
             CONDA_PREFIX=/home/chandsum/miniconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/chandsum/miniconda3/bin/python
              CONDA_QUIET=0
      CONDA_REGISTER_ENVS=true
               CONDA_ROOT=/home/suma/miniconda3/install_tmp/_MEIR38PLO
        CONDA_ROOT_PREFIX=/home/suma/miniconda3
      CONDA_SAFETY_CHECKS=disabled
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
          LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/suma/miniconda3/install_tmp/_MEIR38PLO
               LD_PRELOAD=<not set>
      OLD_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
                     PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/game
                          s:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : /home/chandsum/miniconda3
    active env location : /home/chandsum/miniconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/suma/.condarc
 populated config files :
          conda version : 24.1.2
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.10.13.final.0
                 solver : libmamba (default)
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=skylake
                          __conda=24.1.2=0
                          __cuda=11.6=0
                          __glibc=2.35=0
                          __linux=5.15.146.1=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : /home/suma/miniconda3/install_tmp/_MEIR38PLO  (read only)
      conda av data dir : /home/suma/miniconda3/install_tmp/_MEIR38PLO/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/suma/miniconda3/install_tmp/_MEIR38PLO/pkgs
                          /home/suma/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/suma/.conda/envs
                          /home/suma/miniconda3/install_tmp/_MEIR38PLO/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/24.1.2 requests/2.31.0 CPython/3.10.13 Linux/5.15.146.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 ubuntu/22.04.3 glibc/2.35 solver/libmamba conda-libmamba-solver/24.1.0 libmambapy/1.5.6
                UID:GID : 1001:1001
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
If you suspect this error is being caused by a malfunctioning plugin,
consider using the --no-plugins option to turn off plugins.

Example: conda --no-plugins install <package>

Alternatively, you can set the CONDA_NO_PLUGINS environment variable on
the command line to run the command without plugins enabled.

Example: CONDA_NO_PLUGINS=true conda install <package>

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers? [y/N]: y
Upload did not complete.


I checked the SHA256 hash and it matches with the official website. Anyone who has encountered this issue and has gotten this resolved?

Does /home/chandsum exist in WSL2? Seems like it wants to use that rather than /home/suma/

The path /home/chandsum is the admin path. I was trying to install it for the user /home/suma/. Should I have to change the location of installation?

Since it's the admin path, that would explain the permission denied error. There should be a way to just install for the current user and not mess with other users home holders
